# Is possible to add a variable to a write file path in node-red?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, node-red

Is it possible to add local data on the creation of a file in node red?

Something like this:
`.\Documentos\Teste-node\tes_{{new Date().toLocaleString()}}.csv`

Need to create this csv file with the creation date on it and only one a day. Is this possible using node-red blocks? Or i need to hard code it?

[image: What i tried]

need to have a file like: tes_01/01/2023.csv

(English ins't my first language, sorry for any misspelling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sidebar documentation for the write-file node:

> **filename** *string*
>
> The name of the file to be updated can be provided in the node
> configuration, or as a message property. By default it will use
> msg.filename but this can be customised in the node.

This means if you leave the filename field blank in the configuration, you can pass it in as `msg.filename` on the input message.